# Сравнивание диапазонов из двух массивов PHP

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, циклы, сравнение

Имеются 2 массива: `$times` и `$zhurnal`

Задача: удалить из массива `$times` все элементы, которые входят в диапазон элементов `$zhurnal`, то есть ключи массивов - это начало диапазона, а значения - это конец диапазона.

Пример массива `$times`:

```
$times = [
    [600 => 660], [660 => 720], [720 => 780], [780 => 840], [840 => 900], [900 => 960],
    [960 => 1020], [1020 => 1080], [1080 => 1140], [1140 => 1200], [1200 => 1260]
];
```

Пример массива `$zhurnal` (числа могут быть в любом порядке):

```
$zhurnal = [
    [660 => 720], [600 => 660]
];
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно удалить из массива `$times` элементы , которые входят в диапазон  элементов `$zhurnal`, если я правильно вас понял, то попробуйте такой вариант:

```
function array_diff_gaps($array1, $array2)
{
    $prevnext = function($a) {
        return array_map(function($j) {
            return array_merge(array_keys($j), array_values($j));
        }, $a);
    };

    $array2 = array_reduce($prevnext($array2), 'array_merge', []);

    foreach($prevnext($array1) as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($array2 as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($v, range($value[0], $value[1]))) unset($array1[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array1;
}
```

Пример использования функции `array_diff_gaps`:

```
$times = [
    [600 => 660], [660 => 720], [720 => 780], [780 => 840], [840 => 900], [900 => 960],
    [960 => 1020], [1020 => 1080], [1080 => 1140], [1140 => 1200], [1200 => 1260]
];

$zhurnal = [
    [660 => 720], [600 => 660]
];

print_r(array_diff_gaps($times, $zhurnal));
```

Получаем следующий результат ([*см. демо*](https://ideone.com/9XYHsJ))

Comment: А если значения будут [[640 => 650], [680 => 800]], то уже не работает

Comment: @webdelo24, дайте пример двух массивов, и ожидаемый результат

Comment: @lets-say-pie Пример в вопросе написал, просто в ключах и значениях постоянно меняются значения. Суть в том, что есть диапазоны: ключ - начало диапазона, значение - конец. Например массив **$zhurnal** [660 => 720], массив **$times** [[640 => 650], [680 => 800]], надо сделать так: если любой элемент массива **$times** входит в диапазон 660 => 720 (может и не полностью входить, а только задевать), то этот элемент нужно удалить

Comment: @webdelo24, посмотрите, обновил ответ.

Comment: @webdelo24, если что-то не так, или возникли вопросы, напишите.

Comment: @lets-say-pie Отлично, заработало! Спасибо большое!
Все голову ломал пару дней...